# Adapt custom Illustrator UI for React Native app

Tags: android, react-native, user-interface, svg, adobe-illustrator

I'm building app with one main activity which UI looks like TV remote. I need to show interactive response to the user when he interacts with UI through taps.

UI is created with Illustrator. I was searching for some SVG solutions but only found animation and morph libraries. Turns out I need to reload part of the UI, because reloading everything on every tap seems heavy on performance.

What good solutions there are for this problem? Load SVG in parts and put it together with css? I'm even considering moving to native Android if there's no way, because my app depends on some phone hardware control. By the way, I'll also be moving design to Adobe XD for prototype creation, so maybe there's something to go in line to make life easier.

Comment: Basically what I'm trying to achieve is react to a section of big svg being pressed

Answer (score 1):

So here's a way I solved this:

1. Give names to illustrator layers to be exported (even hidden layers should be shown to be exported)
2. Export selected artboard as SVG with internal CSS and select 'layer names' for Object IDs
3. Open SVG in editor and adjust initial styling as needed (gradient, stroke, hide layers to be switched etc).
4. Use [SVGR](https://react-svgr.com/) to convert SVG into React component
5. Set component position
6. Pass props to React component to change styling at runtime and interact with user